# Excel SSAS data report– Setting Attributes as Properties for dimensions and date fields not formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas

I have some date fields (YYYY-MM-DD) from my SSAS dimension set as properties to be displayed in my Excel report. But when it shown as properties in excel, the date field is converted to datetime format as YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.0000000. I had tried

1. Changing the attribute data type property in my dimension to WChar
2. Tried formatting the cell in excel

Both of these options are not working. Any handy solutions?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed. Underlying datasource was datetime2 field and changed it to date field.